# Get Image URLs from Flickr JSON

Tags: android, json, flickr

I am having trouble getting URLs for images via the Flickr API. I am doing something similar for Instagram and it is working but when my Flickr activity loads, nothing shows up. The JSON is loaded but the issue seems to be with getting the URLs for the images. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class FlickrActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public static GridView gridView;
    public static GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;

    static String url;

    static ArrayList<String> picURLS;

    static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);

        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.imageGrid);
        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this);
        // gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        getActionBar().setTitle("Flickr");

        url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=API KEY&per_page=50&user_id=52540720@N02&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";

        picURLS = new ArrayList<String>();

        new ParseJSON().execute();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FlickrActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class JSONParser {
        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser()
        {

        }

        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String jsonUrl)
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(jsonUrl);
            String responseBody = "DEFAULT_MSG_TEXT";
            int resCode = 0;

            try{

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

                int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                resCode = responseCode;

                switch(responseCode) {
                    case 200:
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        if(entity != null) {
                            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                Log.e("Post Error",resCode + "\n Exception" + ex);
                responseBody = "DEFAULT_MSG_TEXT";
            }

            json = responseBody;

            // try to parse the string to a JSON object
            try
            {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;
        }
    }

    public static class ParseJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // get json from url here
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            System.out.println("JSON: " + json);

            try {
                // JSONArray dataArray = json.getJSONArray("photo");
                JSONObject photos = json.getJSONObject("photos");
                JSONArray dataArray = photos.getJSONArray("photo");
                int thumbnailsCount = dataArray.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < thumbnailsCount; i++) {
                    JSONObject farm = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("farm");
                    JSONObject server = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("server");
                    JSONObject id = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("id");
                    JSONObject secret = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("secret");
                    String picURL = String.format("http://farm%s.static.flickr.com/%s/%s_%s_b.jpg", farm, server, id, secret);
                    System.out.println(picURL);
                    picURLS.add(picURL);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage().toString();
            }

            return picURLS;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

            for (String thumb : picURLS) {
                System.out.println(thumb);
            }
        }
    }

    public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        Context context;

        public GridViewAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return picURLS.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.gridImageView);

                // ImageView gridImageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.gridImageView);

                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(picURLS.get(position))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(holder.imageView);

            return row;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{"photos":{"page":1,"pages":254,"perpage":50,"total":"12665","photo":[{"id":"15355145634","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"a142bd54b5","server":"8580","farm":9,"title":"christmas-scott","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15356461163","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"8508527108","server":"8623","farm":9,"title":"Jackson Tolle","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774323510","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"1a69e1bfa6","server":"7476","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15935827796","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"f2925ac043","server":"8650","farm":9,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774324280","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"48fc882459","server":"8639","farm":9,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15775880047","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"81ec9b78ab","server":"7485","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15775585989","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"c5eca94b67","server":"8639","farm":9,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15961599425","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"87093030fd","server":"8627","farm":9,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774200278","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"74ed5b5bda","server":"7554","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15775880667","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"e4a2105e0e","server":"7560","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15339327134","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"7545e69058","server":"7505","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774325070","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"d84e6cd95a","server":"8680","farm":9,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15341979093","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"a30e8f10c6","server":"7541","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15961598125","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"53ceb7f600","server":"8591","farm":9,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15775881157","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"ddd1bf3ab5","server":"7501","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15959628961","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"45daeb449f","server":"7557","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15960946592","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"dea17cf59e","server":"7583","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15961604775","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"95eb392b5b","server":"7480","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15775590449","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"bb419500e6","server":"7557","farm":8,"title":"2013-14 LEAD graduating class","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15341959493","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"e1af801876","server":"7492","farm":8,"title":"Mr. Melton introduces Mr. Haney at General Session","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15960927522","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"afaa266aa9","server":"7563","farm":8,"title":"Mr. Haney Mr. Beck Mr. Melton","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15339308454","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"91ec731e93","server":"7506","farm":8,"title":"Mr. Haney - General Session","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15341959853","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"2e06aa9460","server":"7565","farm":8,"title":"General Session - Mr. Haney","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774182448","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"15aae90810","server":"7544","farm":8,"title":"FFCLA Pres","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15775862227","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"03c0f94763","server":"8569","farm":9,"title":"FFA President","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774307010","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"f7acc992d6","server":"7520","farm":8,"title":"Carl Hurley - humorist","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774065278","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"3b95230951","server":"7515","farm":8,"title":"2014 \"Top County\" - Butler County Farm Bureau","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15341787543","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"5688437582","server":"7499","farm":8,"title":"230","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15341789423","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"e15292294c","server":"7574","farm":8,"title":"229","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774134430","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"de2435b657","server":"7530","farm":8,"title":"228","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15960758462","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"283dce0a2d","server":"8586","farm":9,"title":"227","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15961411555","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"6b69560354","server":"7576","farm":8,"title":"226","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15339139634","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"50b0106bea","server":"7558","farm":8,"title":"225","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15339140194","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"939177dfba","server":"7581","farm":8,"title":"224","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15775402169","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"b0efef29bf","server":"8673","farm":9,"title":"223","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15341794043","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"612e340f7c","server":"7504","farm":8,"title":"222","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15960762422","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"ac059f3245","server":"7525","farm":8,"title":"221","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15959446971","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"58a59d06d8","server":"7574","farm":8,"title":"220","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15960763572","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"114120a5be","server":"7581","farm":8,"title":"219","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774141340","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"93a6471dd7","server":"7482","farm":8,"title":"218","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15961417175","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"e6ed2869d0","server":"7509","farm":8,"title":"217","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15935642466","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"3399f43c92","server":"7514","farm":8,"title":"216","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15775407129","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"887382ab10","server":"7581","farm":8,"title":"215","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15960766212","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"c7e230b59a","server":"8633","farm":9,"title":"214","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774144000","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"2bd9723772","server":"7557","farm":8,"title":"213","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15959451401","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"836b23ea2b","server":"8567","farm":9,"title":"212","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15774145230","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"bb08df2de2","server":"7530","farm":8,"title":"211","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15339149004","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"baf8e95075","server":"7512","farm":8,"title":"210","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15339149524","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"9b8eddb494","server":"8591","farm":9,"title":"209","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15935647536","owner":"52540720@N02","secret":"00aa323a5a","server":"7515","farm":8,"title":"208","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"}
```

It looks like I'm not getting the farm, server, id, and secret to form each url which explains why no images are showing up. What am I doing wrong when getting those?

Comment: Are you getting exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions. Just a blank activity.

Answer (score 0):

farm, server, id, and secret should not be JSONObjects. They should be strings so it should be
 `String farm = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("farm");`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting farm, server, id, and secret, but they are in the third level. You need to look in photos > photo > farm (or server, id, etc). Once you have that data you can make the url. [Check out this page by Flickr for more details.](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html)